# How to scale the font size in pygame based on display resolution?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

`largeText = pygame.font.Font('digifaw.ttf',450)`

Font size is 450 and is suitable for the displaying the text in a full screen display of resolution `1366x768`. How do I change the font size such that it is compatible with other display resolutions ? I looked up the pydocs for [font](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.size) and couldn't find anything related to auto scaling.

**Update:** Here's a snippet of the code

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('digifaw.ttf',450)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've to scale the font manually. If a font is suited for a window with a height of 768, the you've to scale the font by `current_height/768`. e.g.:

```py
h = screen.get_height();
largeText = pygame.font.Font('digifaw.ttf', int(450*h/768))
```

Note, you can use the [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module:

```py
import pygame.freetype

font = pygame.freetype.Font('digifaw.ttf')
```

and the method [`.render_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to), to render the font directly to a surface:

```py
h = screen.get_height()
font.render_to(screen, (x, y), 'text', color, size=int(450*h/768))
```

---

If you want to scale the width and the height of the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) which is rendered by the font, the you've to use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale):

```py
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
ref_w, ref_h = gameDisplay.get_size()
```

```py
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black).convert_alpha()

    cur_w, cur_h = gameDisplay.get_size()
    txt_w, txt_h = textSurface.get_size()
    textSurface = pygame.transform.smoothscale(
        textSurface, (txt_w * cur_w // ref_w, txt_h * cur_h // ref_h))

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
```