# Change the scale of a Text Component

Tags: python, pygame

`UIText` is a subclass of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`.  I would like to change the scale of each text component, similar to how normal sprites can be scaled:

```py
ui_element.rect.width = ui_element.parent_screen.rect.width * self.width_percent
ui_element.image = pg.transform.smoothscale(ui_element.original_image, ui_element.rect.size)
```

The problem with scaling this text component with the above method is that since `UIText` has a different image, setting it to `pg.transform.smoothscale` gets rid of the text, and turns it into a `rect`.

```py
class UIText(UIComponent):

    def __init__(self, text="Hello :)"):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text
        self.size = 12
        self.update_text()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def set_size(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.update_text()

    def update_text(self):
        font = pg.font.SysFont("gothicI", self.size, self.bold, self.italic)
        self.image = font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale the font size in pygame based on display resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855775/how-to-scale-the-font-size-in-pygame-based-on-display-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. `pygame.font.Font.render()` returns an instance of `pygame.Surface`, which you can squash and stretch to your own satisfaction.

```
class UIText(UIComponent):

    def __init__(self, text="Hello"):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text
        self.size = 12

        self.update_text()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def set_scale(self, scale: tuple):  # (width, height)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, scale)

    def set_size(self, size: int):
        self.size = size
        self.update_text()

    def update_text(self):
        font = pg.font.SysFont("gothicI", self.size, self.bold, self.italic)
        self.image = font.render(str(self.text), 1, self.colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```